# Javascript Chrome Extension get data from website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a google chrome extension. It will work on 2 specific website. Lets say facebook and instagram to that websites. Our main site is facebook but the extension will get data from instagram and paste the data to main site. Can you help me with "how can i get data from website" ?

When i write this code it pastes all the site.

```
//in facebook.com
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $.get(**instagramurl**, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        
    });
});
```

Comment: Modern Chrome blocks cross-origin requests in content scripts so you need to do it through the background script, [more info and examples of code](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches).

Comment: I solve the cross-origin request. I just need to solve that problem.